# Can't center absolute position (Tailwind.css)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

**Background & Problem:**

I'm using Tailwind CSS and Alpine.js for a simple search bar that has a dropdown positioned using `absolute`

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/jdonline/pen/YzXpbyJ

When I position the dropdown using `relative`, it positions perfectly as I want it to (but stretches the rest of the page which I don't want). However, when I change this to `absolute`, although it no longer stretches the page, it extends the dropdown wider than expected.

**Example:**

You can see this by clicking the dropdown arrow on the right side of the search bar. You can also see the difference when changing `absolute` to `relative` on **Line 26**

**Question:**

How can I, using Tailwind.css, position the dropdown so it has `absolute` position, but doesn't extend wider than the search bar?

Comment: The link is dead, but perhaps you could also use `inset-y-0`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , the link is no more working, and there is no debugging details as such which is left in the question, it is just a raw question without any context. as the entire question was dependent on the link provided.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is very simple, `position:absolute` should have a parent div with `position:relative`, in your case `relative` is for body I think, You need to give relative to the parent div which is n line number 25,

You can also refer [Position CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```
<div x-show.transition.opacity.duration.700ms="open" class="relative" >
    <div class="absolute inset-x-0 shadow-xl bg-white w-3/4 md:w-2/5 mx-auto -mt-1 rounded-lg rounded-t-none">
```

Answer (score 242):

with tailwind only, you can use the following classes

```css
absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2
```

so, it would be like

```html
<div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"> </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Note that with Tailwind 3, you don't need `transform` anymore. [Cf this doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#automatic-transforms-and-filters)

Answer (score 38):

for Tailwind try this :

```css
absolute m-auto left-0 right-0
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. But why does it work?

Comment: I would like to know too

Comment: It doesn't work for me. maybe it works for direct container not nested

Answer (score 9):

I found my answer in this proposal on the Tailwind Github profile.
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/1531

Adding this utility class it works perfectly:

```css
.inset-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `grid` and the `place-items-center` to place item in the middle e.g.

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 top-0 grid place-items-center">
   <!-- Add your content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to place the item in the center you can also do it with the following classes `absolute left-0 right-0 grid place-items-center`

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute left-0 right-0 grid place-items-center">
   <!-- Add your content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I created an example on the playground
https://play.tailwindcss.com/FPLV9gLqBD

Answer (score 0):

Shortest and functional version:

```
absolute inset-0 m-auto
```